# Javascript: converting special characters of the form %XX%XX?

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I have a bunch of characters which are encoded in the form %XX%XX. How can I display the actual characters with Javascript?

```
Examples of the characters are...
what I have / what I want 
%C5%93 / œ
%C3%A6 / æ
%C3%9F / ß
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return decodeURIComponent("%C5%93%C3%A6%C3%9F"); // "œæß"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in [`decodeURI`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp) or [`decodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) functions.